# jquery animation

Tags: jquery

I have an animation that fires on click.

I have four images and I want to make larger on click and display some text.

problem I'm having is that you can click the images at will and they all start resizing which then causes it to not behave.

here is the html

```
<div id="nav" style="width: 980px; position: absolute; left: 100px; overflow: hidden" >
<div class="item active">
    <img src="images/image1.png" width="148" height="190" />
    <div style="width:350px; position: absolute; left: 250px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 100"> 
        <h2 style="color:#009DD8">Title1</h2>       
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas turpis turpis, rutrum nec euismod ac, mattis eget felis</p>
    </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="item">
    <img src="images/image2.jpg" width="148" height="190" />
    <div style="width:350px; position: absolute; left: 250px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 100">
        <h2 style="color:#902272">Title2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas turpis turpis, rutrum nec euismod ac, mattis eget felis</p></div>
</div>
 <div class="item">
    <img src="images/image3.png"  width="148" height="190" />
    <div style="width:350px; position: absolute; left: -375px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 100">
        <h2 style="color:#68AA41">Title3</h2>    
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas turpis turpis, rutrum nec euismod ac, mattis eget felis</p>
    </div>  
</div>
 <div class="item">
    <img src="images/image4.png" width="148" height="190" />
    <div style="width:350px; position: absolute; left: -395px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 100">
       <h2 style="color:#F5B21D">Title4</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas turpis turpis, rutrum nec euismod ac, mattis eget felis</p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav div.active").animate({"width": 244,"height": 316}, 1500 ).addClass('active');
    $("#nav div.active").find('img').animate({"width": 244, "height": 316}, 1500);
    $("#nav div.active").find('div').fadeIn(100);

    $('#nav div').click(function(){        
        if($(this).hasClass('active'))   
        {  
            $(this).animate({"width": 148, "height": 190}, 1500 ).removeClass('active');
            $(this).find('img').animate({"width": 148, "height": 190}, 1500 );
            $(this).find('div').fadeOut(500);
        }
        else    
        {
            $(this).animate({"width": 244,"height": 316}, 1500 ).addClass('active');
            $(this).find('img').animate({"width": 244, "height": 316}, 1500 );
            $(this).find('div').fadeIn(100);
            $('.active').not(this).find('img').animate({"width": 148,"height": 190}, 1500 );
            $('.active').not(this).find('div').css({"display": "none"});
            $('.active').not(this).animate({"width": 148,"height": 190}, 1500 ).removeClass('active');  
        }
    });
```

});

I have tried adding .stop() in places but this makes thing worse. Any ideas?

i need these lines to fire at the sametime, one resizes the image the other its container div. if i fireone after the other then it screws up

```
$(this).animate({"width": 244,"height": 316}, 1500 ).addClass('active');
$(this).find('img').animate({"width": 244, "height": 316}, 1500 );

$(this).animate({"width": 148, "height": 190}, 1500 ).removeClass('active');
$(this).find('img').animate({"width": 148, "height": 190}, 1500 );
```

i guess what i want to do is delay the click function until the current animation is complete or better still if another is clicked during an animation to cancel it and return to normal state before firing the onclick function

credit to Nicolas C.

i also tried

```
$('#nav div').click(function(){

    if(!$('#nav div').is(':animated'))
    { 
        if($(this).hasClass('active'))   
        {  
            $(this).animate({"width": 148, "height": 190}, 1500 ).removeClass('active');
            $(this).find('img').animate({"width": 148, "height": 190}, 1500 );
            $(this).find('div').fadeOut(500).stop(true, true);
        }
        else    
        {
            $(this).animate({"width": 244,"height": 316}, 1500 ).addClass('active');
            $(this).find('img').animate({"width": 244, "height": 316}, 1500 );
            $(this).find('div').fadeIn(100).stop(true, true);

            $('.active').not($(this)).find('img').animate({"width": 148,"height": 190}, 1500 );
            $('.active').not($(this)).find('div').fadeOut(500).stop(true, true);
            $('.active').not($(this)).animate({"width": 148,"height": 190}, 1500 ).removeClass('active');   
        }
    }
});
```

works but not very user friendly if they are clicking and it doesnt respond

Comment: questions about jquery not css!

Comment: Well than Adam... your question (even without a fiddle), to me, looks pretty like this. That's why I asked about some CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/wzkwN/

Comment: i think i should start using fiddle. you can see the issue if you click on boxes before the animation has finished.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best solution, but try it and let me know if this is what you intend to do, knowing that I replaced your images with 24x24 icons and assumed the final behaviour you are expecting.

separate css file containing:

```
div.item{
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
img.icon{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}

div.content{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}

div.inactive div.content{
    display: none;
}
div.inactive{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

HTML part:

```
<div id="nav" style="width: 980px; position: absolute; left: 100px; overflow: hidden" >
<div class="item inactive">
    <img class="icon" src="images/image1.png" width="16" height="16" />
    <div class="content"> 
        <h2 style="color:#009DD8">Title1</h2>       
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas turpis turpis, rutrum nec euismod ac, mattis eget felis</p>
    </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="item inactive">
    <img class="icon" src="images/image2.png" width="16" height="16" />
    <div class="content">
        <h2 style="color:#902272">Title2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas turpis turpis, rutrum nec euismod ac, mattis eget felis</p></div>
</div>
 <div class="item inactive">
    <img class="icon" src="images/image3.png"  width="16" height="16" />
    <div class="content">
        <h2 style="color:#68AA41">Title3</h2>    
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas turpis turpis, rutrum nec euismod ac, mattis eget felis</p>
    </div>  
</div>
 <div class="item inactive">
    <img class="icon" src="images/image4.png" width="16" height="16" />
    <div class="content">
       <h2 style="color:#F5B21D">Title4</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas turpis turpis, rutrum nec euismod ac, mattis eget felis</p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

javascript part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav div.item').click(function(){
        var myItems = $('.item');
        var pendingAnimation = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < myItems.length; i++)
        {
            if($(myItems[i]).is(':animated')){
                pendingAnimation = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!pendingAnimation){
            //extend the item
            $(this).animate({"width": 700, "height": 150}, 1500 );
            //make it an active item
            $(this).addClass('active');
            //grow the icon
            $(this).find('img').animate({"width": 24, "height": 24}, 1500 );
            //make the content of the item fade in
            $(this).find('div.content').fadeIn(100);

            //Fading out the content of all the other active elements
            $('.item').not($(this)).find('div.content').fadeOut(500);
            //Shrinking all the other active icons
            $('.item').not($(this)).find('img').animate({"width": 16,"height": 16}, 1500 );
            //Shrinking all the other active items
            $('.item').not($(this)).animate({"width": 16,"height": 16}, 1500 );
            //making all the other items as "inactive"
            $('.item.active').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
        }
    });        
});
```

Effect: whenever you click onto an icon, it expands the clicked div.item, makes it active and animates any other "active" element with a reverse animation.

Comment: my css knowledge is not very good, please do not pay attention to useless statements

Comment: Thats more or less what it does already, your code has the same problem. if you click item 1 and before the animation has complete you click item2, item3 and item 4 you have all the animations going on which is not what i want. i'm trying to find a way to delay/cancel/stop the current animation before the click function is  called

Comment: Ok, so I did not undersand what was his issue at first then. I tried his code and it was clearly not display anything right, so I assumed.

Comment: @AdamWright and now? Does it corresponds more to what you want? Or do you just want to delay the animation? I personally would find weird to go on with other animations. However, if you make the animation a bit faster, that could also diminish the issue.

Comment: was just trying a similar thing will post in my main post

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing the `.animate()` call back function -

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$('.active').not(this).animate({"width": 148,"height": 190}, 1500, function() {
   $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use complete callback for other animation like follows:

```
$("first_animation").animate( {"width": 244,"height": 316}, 1500, 'swing',function(){
  $("second_animation").animate( {"width": 244,"height": 316}, 1500, 'swing',function(){
    $("third_animation").animate( {"width": 244,"height": 316}, 1500, 'swing');
  })
})
```

above code will aminate all three div first_animation, second_animation and third_animation. one by one.

Comment: isn't the function callback fired on complete of the first? i want these lines to fire at the same time  

$(this).animate({"width": 244,"height": 316}, 1500 ).addClass('active');
$(this).find('img').animate({"width": 244, "height": 316}, 1500 );